# Delete Button Codes

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Material_Status_DBDataSet.Material_Status_Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Material_Status_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Material_Status_DBDataSet.Material_Status_Table)

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'add
    PL_NOTextBox.Enabled = True
    NAME_OF_THE_JOBTextBox.Enabled = True
    QUANTITYTextBox.Enabled = True
    ITEMTextBox.Enabled = True
    UNITTextBox.Enabled = True
    REMARKSTextBox.Enabled = True
    ACTION_TAKENTextBox.Enabled = True
    Me.Material_Status_TableBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'delete
    Me.Material_Status_TableBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'edit
    PL_NOTextBox.Enabled = True
    NAME_OF_THE_JOBTextBox.Enabled = True
    QUANTITYTextBox.Enabled = True
    ITEMTextBox.Enabled = True
    UNITTextBox.Enabled = True
    REMARKSTextBox.Enabled = True
    ACTION_TAKENTextBox.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    'update
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Material_Status_TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.Material_Status_TableTableAdapter.Update(Me.Material_Status_DBDataSet)
    TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Material_Status_DBDataSet)
    PL_NOTextBox.Enabled = False
    NAME_OF_THE_JOBTextBox.Enabled = False
    QUANTITYTextBox.Enabled = False
    ITEMTextBox.Enabled = False
    UNITTextBox.Enabled = False
    REMARKSTextBox.Enabled = False
    ACTION_TAKENTextBox.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
  'search  Me.Material_Status_TableTableAdapter.SearchPLNO(Me.Material_Status_DBDataSet.Material_Status_Table, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub


End Class
```

Hello, I am new to `vb`. My project has an add, delete & update search buttons that connect with a database called material status. When I run this project it don't permanently delete data record in database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7eah.png) , when delete button pressed. What is wrong here? 
Could you please send me codes for display searching combo box instead of textbox1.

Comment: See if this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx

Comment: And give your buttons names that make sense.... Like btn_Delete..etc... Button1,2,3 etc is hopeless.

Comment: `Could you please send me codes for display searching`, you are not asking a question... and ***no*** that is not how SO works...

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]